# vCard .vcf files Is there a GUI app for importing editing and exporting with out mail clients and LibreOffice etc

Tags: contacts

since couple of hours I am trying to find out a GUI app which can import .vcf file and then editing the names of the contacts or numbers and save it.

I found some apps like kaddressbook and did not remember some other which did not work or buggy..

I am looking for a GUI app for the Ubuntu versions 18.04 and above similar to Outlook Contacts like below

[image]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but have you tried LibreOffice Calc?

Comment: @DK Bose no.. and I may not install LibreOffice Calc also.. I am searching for a GUI app which does not need Thunderbird email client or LibreOffice.. Consider my OS is a minimal install..

Comment: I think it's a plain text file, so maybe even gedit?

Comment: got your point @DKBose but.. the format is not user friendly gedit or LOCalc.. like Outlook Contacts its very user friendly.. something like this https://www.google.com/search?q=outlook+contacts&client=ubuntu&hs=GO2&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjwmq6L2avoAhWHxjgGHUTXBtcQ_AUoA3oECA8QBQ&biw=1920&bih=979#imgrc=XE0xdnZQXIpG4M

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same situation.
I found [Vcard Studio](https://snapcraft.io/vcard-studio) and it seems to be the **only** option.

I'm working on it at this moment, eventually I'll update this reply with my experience.

Comment: I'm looking for the same.  So how'd it go?  Any new options show up in the last two years?

Comment: AFAIK no, unfortunately.

Comment: Antonio, see my answer here.

Comment: I used Radicale for a couple of years for my calendar but I gave up on Google.
I don't want a "big" solution, like servers, I wanted a basic tool, one level up to edit vcf files as text with Vim. :-) Cardbook would be a good solution if it did not have the dependency on Thunderbird.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also in the process of searching. I found what look like a few approaches.

First, Thunderbird has a very good plugin, [CardBook](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/cardbook), which provides import/ export.

Or, you can install a local Card/CalDAV server, like [Radicale](https://radicale.org/v3.html), [Baikal](https://github.com/sabre-io/Baikal/), or something more full-blown, like [SOGo](https://www.sogo.nu/) or [EteSync](https://www.etesync.com/get-apps/).  They all have import/export mechanisms.  I'd similarly mention Nextcloud Contacts, but it seems to be seriously buggy.

Finally, a "vdir" is a directory full of vCards & iCal's. Connect that to [DecSync](https://github.com/39aldo39/DecSync) using [decsync-vdir](https://github.com/luk3yx/decsync-vdir). Then, Evolution and Akondi have DecSync plugins. Radicale also has a DecSync plugin.

I'd love to hear if anyone has more to add!